# Returning data after sorting through multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have nested arrays within an object, and I need to extract these values, and sort them into alphabetical order which will then be displayed in a table.

I am using the `localeCompare` method but it is returning:

```
Cannot read property 'localeCompare' of null
```

To be honest, I am not sure I am approaching this correctly. Using `sort` you can compare `a` to `b` to sort them into alphabetical order. I am getting confused how to compare the values from the arrays within `a` and `b`. I am using the first `sort` on `tableData` to access the array, and the using a second `sort` to compare the values that I pushed to array `clientRefArr`

```
if(params.sorting().clientRef) {

        var clientRefArr = [];

        tableData.sort(function(a, b){

            a.renewalUIs.forEach(function(data, i){
                clientRefArr.push(data.patentUI.clientRef);
            })

            return clientRefArr.sort(function(a, b){
                console.log(a.localeCompare(b))
                // return a.localeCompare(b)
            })

        })

    orderedData = tableData;

}

return orderedData;
```

***Question***

Why is the error `Cannot read property 'localeCompare' of null` being returned?Am I approaching this issue completely wrong?

```
//JSON

[
 0: {
     transRef: "IX1000013"
     renewalProgress: 30
     renewalUIs: [
        0: {
            patentUI: {
               business: null
               clientRef: P0101011 // this is the required value 
            }
            renewalAttemptsMade: 1
            renewalDueDate: 1514764740000
         }
     ]

   },
 1: {
     transRef: "IX100333"
     renewalProgress: 55
     renewalUIs: [
        0: {
            patentUI: {
               business: null
               clientRef: P0101011 // this is the required value 
            }
            renewalAttemptsMade: 1
            renewalDueDate: 1514764740000
         },
        1: {
            patentUI: {
               business: null
               clientRef: P5551011 // this is the required value 
            }
            renewalAttemptsMade: 3
            renewalDueDate: 174834740000
         }
     ]

   }
]
```

Comment: You are not testing if you are passed anything: `if (a && b) console.log(a.localeCompare(b))` Also you are sorting inside a sort?

Comment: @mplungjan thank you. Yeah this why I said I don't think I am approaching this right manner

Comment: How do I access the data from `tableData`, extract the nested array items, then compare the items in the array and return it to the `tableData.sort`>

Comment: Am i right in thinking from [1,[8,5,3],4] you want to return [1,3,4,5,8]?

Comment: Sorting strings alphabetically and returning it to `tableData.sort()`

Comment: it looks like you take a value out of an array for sorting the outer array...?

Comment: Correct. What you have answered so far is resulting in the correct behavior when logged. Though it won't sort the table still

Comment: it would help, if you add some real data, not only the structure.

Comment: Just added further data. Hope it helps

Comment: which one of the inner value do you like to use for sorting for the outer array?

Comment: clientRef is the value I require

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159174/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-patrick-mcdermott).

Answer (score 1):

You could take a default value for both parts

```
(a || '').localeCompare(b || '')
```

for sorting the `null` values or even all [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values to top.

An attempt with the given data (I changed some value, to get some sorting).

It now sorts the inner arrays `renewalUIs` first and then it takes the first element for sorting the outer array.

```js
var array = [{ transRef: "IX1000013", renewalProgress: 30, renewalUIs: [{ patentUI: { business: null, clientRef: "P9101011" }, renewalAttemptsMade: 1, renewalDueDate: 1514764740000 }] }, { transRef: "IX100333", renewalProgress: 55, renewalUIs: [{ patentUI: { business: null, clientRef: "P7101011" }, renewalAttemptsMade: 1, renewalDueDate: 1514764740000 }, { patentUI: { business: null, clientRef: "P5551011" }, renewalAttemptsMade: 3, renewalDueDate: 174834740000 }] }];

array.forEach(function (o) {
    o.renewalUIs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.patentUI.clientRef.localeCompare(b.patentUI.clientRef);
    });
});

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.renewalUIs[0].patentUI.clientRef.localeCompare(b.renewalUIs[0].patentUI.clientRef);
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Solved the issue of the error of `Cannot read property 'localeCompare' of null`. Still no success in sorting the data

Comment: you may add the data to the question for a closer look to the structure.

Comment: Just added the JSON structure

Answer (score 0):

IF my interpretation is correct, it'd be way easier to first put everything in an single array and then sort it as such just use loops for the first task and a normal sort for the second, nested sorts are really just a bad idea.

```
// let's assume your data is in unorderedData
var clientUIs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < unorderedData.length; i++){
  for (var j = 0 ; j < unorderedData[i]["renewalUIs"].length; j++){
     // add each UI to your list individually.
     clientUIs.push(unorderedData[i]["renewalUIs"][j]["patentUI"]);
  }
}
clientUIs.sort() //just sort everything
tableData = clientUIs;
```

If "renewalUIs" or "patentUIs" arent constant you can iterate over the keys of the dictionary.

Comment: Well I've tried that and it did someting. Not what I wanted but it's progress. tableData holds the unordered data. Create a second variable or is it OK to use tableData for the for loop?

Comment: I added `.clientRef` to the `clientUIs.push(unorderedData[i]["renewalUIs"][j]["patentUI"])` syntax as it is this value I need to sort the data by